# Iterating hashes in Ansible only saves the last result in the register

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible script that is taking disk images in a specified directory, iterating over them, and importing them to RHEV.  I have it working except that it only ever imports the last disk image.

The image information is stored in a hash variable I create with information pulled from the disk.  Everything is working as expected for the import and I am assuming I have done something wrong with saving the values for the hash that I have called "disk_image_info".  This is in the task "Gather information for import".

I also see that older versions of Ansible have had issue that sound very similar to this but I am using a version that should have the fixes in it:

```
ansible 2.6.12
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

My tasks are as follows:

```
- name: Extract image
  unarchive:
    src: "{{item}}"
    dest: "{{rhev_image_tmp}}"
    list_files: true
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{rhev_image_tmp}}/*.tar.gz"
  register: extracted_image
  when: directory_created is succeeded

- name: Get the image size
  shell: qemu-img info "{{item}}" | grep 'virtual size' | awk '{print $3}'
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{rhev_image_tmp}}/*.qcow2"
  register: disk_size
  when: extracted_image is succeeded

- name: Gather file information for import
  set_fact:
    disk_image_info:
      name: "{{item.files[0]}}" # There is always only one file here for my situation
      size: 40G #"{{disk_size.results}}" # Will fix hard code later
      src: "{{item.dest}}/{{item.files[0]}}" # There is always only one file here for my situation
  with_items: "{{extracted_image.results}}"

- name: Load disk image into RHEV
  ovirt_disk:
    auth: "{{rhevm_auth}}"
    name: "{{item.name}}"
    interface: virtio
    size: "{{item.size}}iB"
    format: cow
    image_path: "{{item.src}}"
    storage_domain: "{{gluster_storage_name}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{disk_image_info}}"
  when: disk_size is succeeded
```

EDIT:
I have confirmed that my loop is overwriting previous entries in the task "Gather file information for import".  So the list of items getting fed into that task is working as expected.

UPDATE:
I made changes to the task with clockworknet's help and have come up with the following, but it is still resulting in the overwrite of the values:

```
- name: Gather file information for import
  include: set_image_info.yml
  with_items: "{{extracted_image.results}}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: disk_image_info
```

set_image_info.yml:

```
- name: Set disk_image_info
  set_fact:
    disk_image_info:
        name: "{{disk_image_info.files[0]}}"
        size: 40G
        src: "{{disk_image_info.dest}}/{{disk_image_info.files[0]}}"
- name: Output disk info iteration
  debug:
    msg: "{{disk_image_info}}"
```

Also, for reference I am getting the following from my unarchive register:

```
changed: [dev1.dds.io] => (item=/var/images/Kali_Disk1.qcow2.tar.gz) => {
    "changed": true, 
    "dest": "/var/images", 
    "extract_results": {
        "cmd": [
            "/bin/gtar", 
            "--extract", 
            "-C", 
            "/var/images", 
            "-z", 
            "-f", 
            "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549567288.17-253158870541109/source"
        ], 
        "err": "/bin/gtar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `LIBARCHIVE.creationtime'\n/bin/gtar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'\n/bin/gtar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'\n/bin/gtar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'\n", 
        "out": "", 
        "rc": 0
    }, 
    "files": [
        "Kali_Disk1.qcow2"
    ], 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "handler": "TgzArchive", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null, 
            "backup": null, 
            "content": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "dest": "/var/images", 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "exclude": [], 
            "extra_opts": [], 
            "follow": false, 
            "force": null, 
            "group": null, 
            "keep_newer": false, 
            "list_files": true, 
            "mode": null, 
            "owner": null, 
            "regexp": null, 
            "remote_src": false, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549567288.17-253158870541109/source", 
            "unsafe_writes": null, 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "item": "/var/images/Kali_Disk1.qcow2.tar.gz", 
    "mode": "0755", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "secontext": "unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0", 
    "size": 64, 
    "src": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549567288.17-253158870541109/source", 
    "state": "directory", 
    "uid": 0
}
```

Comment: Using `register` on a task driven by a loop is rarely likely to do what you want. The data stored in the variable, will be overwritten on each pass of the loop. I think you need to look at splitting each looped task out into its own include file, add a `set_fact` task in the include file to append the registered variable in either a list or dictionary construct, then attach the loop to the `include`, task. Once it completes the newly set fact will either contain a list or dictionary of results from each pass of the loop.

Comment: So I created the new task file to import and stuck the loop on the tasks with the includes and am getting an error stating it is unsupported operand types.  They are both AnsibleUnsafeText types.  Do I have to convert the extracted_image.results that are being passed into the loop?

Comment: I think you need to use some debug statements to look at what your variables actually contain. I don't think they contain what you think you do. When you use `register` it stores the output of the__module__. This includes a bunch of meta data about the module, together with some form of output from the task it completes. I say this, because I have no idea where you get `extracted_image.results` from. When I test with `unarchive` and register its output, there is no `results` element.

Comment: Sorry, I had some brackets missing that was causing the error.  I have updated the question with troubleshooting additions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, just easier to format than the comments section. Starting at the top you have:

```
- name: Extract image
  unarchive:
    src: "{{item}}"
    dest: "{{rhev_image_tmp}}"
    list_files: true
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{rhev_image_tmp}}/*.tar.gz"
  register: extracted_image
  when: directory_created is succeeded
```

So this task will look for all the files located at `"{{rhev_image_tmp}}/*.tar.gz"`. Then, for each file found, it will run the `unarchive` module, storing the output of that module in `extracted_image`. This means that when you move onto the later tasks, `extracted_image` will contain the output from **last** time around the loop only.

When you get to `- name: Gather file information for import` you then try and loop around `with_items: "{{extracted_image.results}}"`, but you have shown in the output you have posted from `extracted_image` that it does not contain a 'results' key - so I am not understanding what is supposed to be happening there.

You also do exactly the same with `- name: Get the image size`, so you end up with 'disk_size' again containing only the output from the last time around the loop.

So an example of how to handle registering the output of a loop:

```
---
- name: Loop through the tarballs
  include: extract_image.yml
  with_fileglob: "{{rhev_image_tmp}}/*.tar.gz"
- name: Show the registered data
  debug:
    var: extracted_images
```

extract_image.yml

```
---
- unarchive:
    src: "{{item}}"
    dest: "{{rhev_image_tmp}}"
    list_files: true
  register: image_data
- set_fact:
    extracted_images: "{{ extracted_images | default({}) | combine( {item | basename: image_data} ) ) }}"
```

So that will get you a dictionary of dictionaries containing the output of each pass of the loop. You would also need to do this for the other loops.

You still need to figure out how to construct the 'disk_image_info' dictionary.

I would suggest getting the two loops dealt with first and then look at the contents of the two variables with the debug module. Once you understand the structure you can then figure out how to extract the relevant data to create 'disk_image_info'.